# SMS Retriever API - Android app hash is visible on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, google-play, twilio, google-play-services

I use `SMS Retriever API` in Android and to do so I format a text message as:

```
<#>Your verification code is: 123456
He42w354ol9
```

On Android it works well but in case the user has an iPhone it will receive a SMS and the "encoded part" is visible, it will see the raw message above whereas I expect him to see only:

```
Your verification code is: 123456
```

Since I cannot know in advance if the user is on Android/iPhone (I just have the phone number), what are the solutions to make `SMS Retriever API` working on Android but the encoding logic hidden on iPhone?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to modify SMS on iPhone, the only possible way to solve this is, that you need to identify the type of the user before sending the SMS from twilio, so if it is an Android/iOS user then send the SMS accordingly.